# PHP Class functions that are neither methods nor static

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I want a function in my class to perform a simple task, such as:

`function hello($name)
{
return 'hello '.$name;
}`

i.e. Not necessarily static (though I suppose it might be), but not related to the object (no reference to $this necessary).

Do I use a static function? ie.

`static function hello($name){return 'hello '.$name;}`

and call it using `$string = ClassName::hello('Alex');`

or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: *(tip)* [Static considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class methods which don't require an instance of object to be called and which should be able to be executed without an instance of object should be declared as static.

Static methods don't have $this and should be called as ClassName::methodName().

Static methods can access static member variables of their class.

Comment: I thought as much; I was just irritated by calling the static function because it looks strange - still getting used to using Objects with PHP. Thanks!

Comment: A good practice is to put all your functions into classes or namespaces. Better than having a ton of global functions.

Answer (score 2):

A static function should be a static function.
If it is stateless, than use static.

You may also encapsulate group of similar functions in a class *Utils. so these functions will be like helpers

```
class StringUtils{
function splitBy($delimeter,$val){....}
}

than you call it StringUtils::splitBy(..)
```

meaning if it is not related to the object, seperate it.

You can take with you the utils folder to every project and reuse it on and on and on....

Comment: @Gordon, y? any chance to reuse a function inside an unrelated object?
It is bad to `UserEntity::SplitString($...)` how can a different programmer find that? I think this better `StringUtils::SplitString($...)`

Comment: Because an object should have methods that operate on it's own internal state. An object that doesnt do that is lacking coherence and that's a sure sign of a misplaced method. Grouping seemingly related functions into a class scope is basically just abusing the class for a namespace.

Comment: Through Strategy Patterns and/or Polymorphism.

Comment: I dont see how can you solve these issues with Strategy Patterns and/or Polymorphism. If you want to reuse a simple method like myArrayUnique() and you want to do it across the system, you need to separate it from your Business logic , models and entities. BTW, this is how Spring and Apache wrote their frameworks in JAVA.

Comment: myArrayUnique, like the name implies, is a method that should be on an Array object. PHP's native ArrayObject doesnt have that, but you could easily add the method by extending ArrayObject. For the regular array type, there already is a unique method (and its not slapped onto some Utils class, but a global function). On a sidenote, I dont get notified about replies if you dont put my name into the reply.

Comment: @Gordon... myArrayUnique is just an example for a simple helper that you may need across your plasform(s!), it can also be getNubersFromText or parseMyOwnTemplatesFromText, so separating these methods will help you reuse it in current or other systems.  so in java you take the utils jar into your project in use its static methods. for example: http://bit.ly/oA5VMA. I think that strategy Patterns/p.m meant for reusing properties and methods form the family of an object . have a look at this http://bit.ly/oA5VMA just insert the jar and call your helpers...

Comment: ArrayUtils is a wonderful example of a harmful component. Why arent these methods on the Array object? Using them statically will create a hard coupled dependency and will make the code harder to test and maintain. If you need these methods, put them on the object or aggregate the object, e.g. make the Utils a Decorator. As for Strategy: filter and validators come to my mind. You wouldn't want to have these on a giant Utils class. You'd simply capsule all the filter/validation logic into a single class and inject those where needed.

Comment: @Gordon ... Lets agree to disagree. I can't see a situation where I need to extend a class in order to get "mechanic" functionality such as  getNubersFromText ....

Comment: agreed then. oh, make sure you check out the link I posted below the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. what for this function in this class?  if it not belong to it - just move somewhere else
2. ... if belongs then the question is in possibility to call it without creating object

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reference to $this (or possible future reference to $this) make it static.

I say this because sometimes I go with:

```
static function hello( $name ) { return 'hello '.$name; }
```

and after a few months of developing and expanding the program I feel the need to reference $this, like:

```
function hello( $name ) { return $this->helloInLanguage[ $this->language ].' '.$name; };
```